# need to configure an old JDBCRealm for tomcat webapp with oracle database

Tags: forms, oracle, tomcat, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I am trying to resurrect some  old java webapps but lost my old glassfish config files in which my JDBCRealm was defined.  Now I am trying to deploy the old war's to Tomcat 7 and need to recreate the JDBCRealm to authenticate users.  It's been so long since I worked on this stuff I can't remember how to do it, I looked a the official doc but it lacks a connectionURL for oracle.  I think my database is set up as before with the users and roles table.

Can I even reuse the old war that ran on glassfish 3 on Tomcat 7?  It contains a sun-web.xml file. Is that just for glassfish?

I am using form auth method - here is s  snippet of my web.xml:

```
 <login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<realm-name>jdbc/myapp/realm</realm-name>
<form-login-config>
  <form-login-page>/loginPage.jsp</form-login-page>
  <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

Here is my realm snippet from  server.xml file:

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
      resourceName="UserDatabase"/>

  </Realm>


  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm" 
driverName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
   userTable="users"userNameCol="username" 
userCredCol="wpassword"userRoleTable="roles"roleNameCol="rolename"/>
```

Does my connectionURL look right?  What else might be wrong?  Right now when I try to login it never accepts my password.  I always get my login error page (not a full app crash ).

Latest realm version:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
       driverName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
       connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"
       connectionName="uname"
       connectionPassword="pword_33"
       userTable="USERS"
       userNameCol="USERNAME"
       userCredCol="WPASSWORD"
       userRoleTable="ROLES"
       roleNameCol="ROLENAME" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The connection URL looks ok, assuming the database sid is XE. You seem to be missing the connectionName and connectionPassword attributes. Any attribute listed in bold in the [docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/realm.html) is required.

Comment: tried it but still no luck, -- see latest version of my realm above.

Comment: Then one of the above settings is incorrect (and only you can tell which) or the username and password you are using doesn't match one in the database or doesn't have the necessary role. Turning on debug logging for the org.apache.catalina.authenticator package should give you some clues as to where things are going wrong (assuming you are using container managed authentication).

Comment: could my windows firewall be blocking it even though it's running locally?  will try the debug logging when I get home.  Thanks

Comment: ok, I decided to just remove the JDBCRealm and just use xml files - so in my case tomcat-users to define my users.  I deleted the realmname element and defined a few users in tomcatusers - what else tdo I need to do to make this work?  Now I get a 403 error when I go to the protected page.  so the system is not finding my users.  Also, i previously had this deployed to glassfish, do need to remove the old sun-web.xml file?

Comment: ok I got around my probs by changing my  url-patterns to point to bogus stuff.  thanks.